# Touchpad inertia scrolling everywhere 16.04

Tags: gnome, google-chrome, touchpad, scrolling

If I scroll with a touchpad in apps like nautilus and the software center in 16.04, I get a nice smooth result which has inertia scrolling (I think it's called that, maybe momentum or coasting). But if I scroll in apps  like chrome and sublime I don't get the same result. Scrolling is fairly smooth but it doesn't feature the inertia scrolling that system apps have.

Is there anyway to make everything have the same result? I'm using libinput for the touchpad (synaptics alongside libinput seems to create a few issues).

Here is a quick video of the issue I'm having. I'm scrolling both windows with the same two finger swipe action. You can see software center gives me inertia and chrome doesn't.

https://youtu.be/Y1zOFHA9Obc

Comment: `libinput` doesn't support inertia scrolling. Check what are you using by `xinput list-props ID`.